# Remote start and Cool down ford F150 2015: possible by interfacing with ODBii?

Tags: obd-ii, can-bus, remote-start

I'm trying to set remote starter and cool down (Air conditioning), of my Ford f150 2015...

I have done an initial reserarch and it seems possible (I have found a company called Start x https://remotestartx.com/ )...

The company seems to be out of stocks for my car specific remote starter component, therefore, considering I like challenges and I like to get my hands dirty, I am planning to "built it myself"...

Checked the Ford official development API site,but my car is not listed https://developer.ford.com/apis

I have seen online few ODBii CAN-bus development kit: will they work? Is there any good guide tor them?

I would love some initial guidance to kick it off!

Thank you all!

Comment: What's your background on EFI, factory antitheft systems and electronics in general? Most vehicle antitheft/immobilizer systems are programmed (baked) into various modules, making them difficult for average diyers attempting mods but not to aftermarket companies in business to market remote start systems.

Comment: I am not familiar with car specific systems (EFI, antitheft etc...) I am familiar with Code development (Java, C#, JavaScript etc..), electronics (nodeMCU, Arduino etc).. but wiling to learn...  

where would you suggest to start?

Comment: Just [add the factory one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHhO3nI0F4g). It will be easier, more reliable, and importantly, much safer than trying to roll your own or even an aftermarket solution.

Comment: @user71659, I like this, but what is missing is the remote (via mobile) control... this is only with the key fob.... which is a limitation for my use-case... but definitely a good startign pint, which proves that it is doable :)

Answer (score 0):

Acquire factory service manuals from Ford, Alldata.diy or Mitchell data. Alldata and Mitchell have subscription fees providing the same service manuals online, the same as Ford. Info on basic electronic fuel injection, terms used by each manufacturer, and theft deterrent/immobilizer systems can give you invaluable info on where some factory remote start systems are programmed and integrated into engine and body/chassis control modules. Be aware that none of the manufacturers provide software info, only wiring pinouts where signals enter/exit. You have to decifer which signals relate to theft detection, deterrent by immobilizing part of the EFI system and if factory remote start is imbedded, if it's enabled as an option or standard. ECMs are separate from other modules, to run the entire EFI system. Body/chassis modules run remote start, antitheft, interior/exterior lighting, gauges and gateway for collating all modules generating error codes and sent to the body/chassis module for output thru the OBD II port. Programming thru the OBDII port may be via separate canbus (paired wires) or thru either serial or another set of wires in the OBDII pinouts. In other words, you must have an understanding how Ford electronics and language protocols works before attempting to custom make a diy interface for remote starting.

Comment: wow! this is a real well done explanation...  I will definitely start with what you suggested... and then, probably come back here for more questions :)